# Spring's persistence exception translation not working with Hibernate 5

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using Spring 4.3.10 and Hibernate 5.2.10 (I've migrated from Hibernate 4 since which moment got into below problem). The following post-processor is declared in order to take advantage of Spring's translation of Hibernate exceptions in my `@Repository`-marked service.

```
@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor() {
   return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}
```

My code violates a DB constraint, so Hibernate will throw a `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException` which I expect to translate into Spring's generic `org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException`. However, what was working in Hibernate 4 does not in 5.

As I see from the source code, Hibernate 5 uses internally its `ExceptionConverter` which wraps the `ConstraintViolationException` with a JPA's `javax.persistence.PersistenceException`. Here's how Spring's `LocalSessionFactoryBean`'s `translateExceptionIfPossible()` (inherited from `HibernateExceptionTranslator`) looks like:

```
@Override
public DataAccessException translateExceptionIfPossible(RuntimeException ex) {
   if (ex instanceof HibernateException) {
      return convertHibernateAccessException((HibernateException) ex);
   }
   return null;
}
```

An instance of `PersistenceException` instead of a bare Hibernate exception comes here, so translation won't happen.

I still admit the problem is mine as I couldn't find anyone facing this problem with such a popular usage. Any Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: FYI JPA spec says always throw PersistenceException (with whatever detail exception nested).

Comment: @NeilStockton Spring still doesn't seem to bother about unwrapping to do a proper translation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a configuration issue. The problem was in `spring-orm` library which was of version 4.3.1 while the rest of Spring components were of 4.3.10. In the newer version, `HibernateExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible()` looks upgraded:

```
@Override
public DataAccessException translateExceptionIfPossible(RuntimeException ex) {
   if (ex instanceof HibernateException) {
      return convertHibernateAccessException((HibernateException) ex);
   }
   if (ex instanceof PersistenceException) {
      if (ex.getCause() instanceof HibernateException) {
         // this is my case!
         return convertHibernateAccessException((HibernateException) ex.getCause());
      }
      return EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(ex);
   }
   return null;
}
```

Now it works as expected.